# some problem with "docker exec" to execute "patch -R -p0 < translation.patch"

Tags: docker

I'm trying to patch a directory in a docker container but a strange problem bothers me.

I run

```
docker exec -w /opt/explorer 976944b28416 patch -R -p0 < translation.patch
```

and got an error

```
bash: translation.patch: No such file or directory
```

But I'm sure that the file translatioin.patch is there.

Here is the directory structure in docker container:

```sh
docker exec -w /opt/explorer 976944b28416 ls
...
client
...
translation.patch
...
```

I suspect that the `<` symbol in command has caused the problem, but I don't know what the specific situation is.

Comment: Sorry, I made this mistake when I wrote the question description. I have  changed it. The problem is still there.

Comment: You're redirecting the input of the `docker exec` command, which happens outside of the container.

Comment: Try `docker exec ... sh -c 'patch -R -p0 < translation.patch'` as described in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#extended-description).

Comment: It works. But the patch doesn't work. Maybe there are some other mistakes in my operation. I will check it later.  Thank you very much.